# options for select outputting blank values and label values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to populate a select tag from an array of hashes. When I use options_for_select, it's outputting the correct number of options, but value label and option text is not there.

```
[{:name=>"Label", :id=>"326613406", :thumb=>"https://something/whatever"},another hash]

formatted_options = options_for_select(select_options.collect { |f| [ f['name'], f['id'], {'data-thumb' => f['thumb']} ] })

return select_tag "#{object.class.to_s.downcase + '[content][' + field.name + ']'}", formatted_options, {class: "image-support-select"}
```

I would expect that the value and text of the option elements would show. Also, I'd like to include a data attribute for each option tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your hash keys as `symbol` but in your loop you are accessing them as `string`.

Change your loop like this:

```
formatted_options = options_for_select(select_options.collect { |f| [ f[:name], f[:id], {'data-thumb' => f[:thumb]} ] })
```

If you want to access your hash both by using `symbol` keys and `string` keys, you can call [`with_indifferent_access`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/with_indifferent_access) method of hash

In that case you need to change your hash like this:

```
[{:name=>"Label", :id=>"326613406", :thumb=>"https://something/whatever"}.with_indifferent_access]
```